# Problem connecting to MySql

Tags: mysql, vbscript

I am trying to connect to MySql server from my ASP VB application.

The connection string i use is :

```
Driver=org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver;Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```

The code i use to connect is :

```
public sub sqlCommand(objCommand, strSqlCommand)

    'run query using the command object
    set objCommand = server.createobject("ADODB.Command")
    response.Write(application("database_connectionstring_external"))
    objCommand.ActiveConnection = application("database_connectionstring_external")
    objCommand.CommandText = strSqlCommand
    objCommand.CommandType = adCmdText

end sub
```

I am getting error '80004005'

what is the problem in code ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error 80004005 usually means wrong username/password have you checked whether those work manually?